# Issues with comparing a character from a string to a specific character

Tags: c++

I am attempting to compare the last character in a string variable to one of two specific characters in order to signal for a loop to end.

At the moment the loop starts and will gather characters as planned, however the loop does not exit even when it should be detecting the given characters for exiting.

The loop resembles this:

```
string svar;
string temp;

while(svar[svar.size()-1] != '.')
{
istream << temp;
svar += temp;
}
```

The actual loop is being used for an overridden extraction operator for a program I am writing.

Comment: I assume you really mean `istream >> temp`?

Comment: As for your problem, can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? Together with some example input that causes your problems to happen? And you *have* tried to step through the code with a debugger, to see what `svar` and `temp` actually are? Or at least add dome printouts of the variables (inside quotes, for example, so make sure there's no trailing unexpected spaces)?

Comment: you are updating the size of svar every time (svar += temp;). That's why loop will not end

Comment: `svar` starts empty. So what does  `svar[svar.size()-1]` translate to?

Comment: In addition to `istream >> temp` you should check the stream state. What happens if end of stream is reached or there is a read error before the '.' character is reached? Then you will loop endlessly. Fix it like this: `while(istream && svar[svar.size()-1] != '.')`